# SSH and remote desktop solution for iOS

Tags: ssh, remote-desktop, macos

My brother is looking into upgrading his MacBook Pro and is worried about carrying a €4k hardware around. Sometimes he works from home and sometimes at his office.

Since he has an older iMac (not sure on the specs!), I suggested him to go for the new MacBook, leave it either at home or at the office and access it remotely and grab a couple of 4k screens to expand his desktop.

I have done that extensively on Windows and Linux platforms and I dare say there is a good paid solution for this. The idea would be using the higher spec new MacBook (that would be connected to high-speed broadband either at the office or his home) as a local machine, including the GPU. Evidently, for security reasons, the connection back and forth should be in an SSH tunnel. Is this feasible?

Either at the office (a co-working place) or at home he should be under an "*off-the-shelf*" broadband service, which distributes IPs via DCHP. I thought of a solution like a dynamic DNS provider but would much prefer a client to handle both the SSH tunnel and remote host address. Is there a software suite that would help him out?

Comment: "Remote desktop for iOS" is a very broad question, I am sure there are dozens of solutions available. Do you have special requirements? Please develop the last paragraph to explain what IP is changing (server? client?) and whether you expect to be able to use the software with no hiccup at all during such changes. Thanks!

Comment: @NicolasRaoul, is this more clear? I really don't if on his co-working place they implement some sort of firewall...

Comment: Please ask your brother for his IP address, try to ping it from your home, and tell us whether it worked or not. Thanks!